# Undefined variable on sbcl, not on clisp

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, clisp

Loading the following 2 functions on `clisp` goes successful.

```
(defun func1 (l)
  (defvar *count* nil)
  (setq count 1)
  (cond ((null l) 0)
        ((atom l) (+ count 1))
        ((atom (car l)) (+ count (func1 (cdr l))))
        ((listp (car l)) (+ (func1 (car l)) (func1 (cdr l))))
        (t nil))    )
(defun func2 (l)
  (defvar *resLis* nil)
  (setq resLis '((0 0)))
  (anotherFunc l resLis)  
)
```

However, `sbcl` causes error:

```
warning: undefined variable: COUNT
warning: undefined variable: RESLIS
Compilation failed.
```

I prefer using `sbcl` (since my `slime` only goes well with it) but what's wrong with the codes above?

Environment: Ubuntu 11.10, GNU CLISP 2.49, SBCL 1.0.50.0.debian

Comment: what is the colon doing there?

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment to @Arlen Cuss' answer, I just tried to simplify, thinking that part wasn't critical to the question. Since 2 persons wondered, I modified my question to add the hidden part.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SBCL does not 'causes error'. The compiler prints a **warning**. CLISP may not warn, if you use its interpreter and not its compiler. SBCL uses the compiler by default.

What's wrong?

- `DEFVAR` is a top-level form defining a global variable. Using it in a function is possible, but not recommended.
- `count` is simply undefined. As SBCL says. You have nowhere a variable `count` defined.

Comment: I forgot to mention/cite that on `SBCL` compilation fails in addition to print warning (I updated question description), which prevents from execution. And even if I declare `DEFVAR` line outside of function definition, the result is the same.

Comment: So your 2nd bullet (`count` isn't defined) is the reason why `SBCL` returns errors I think. I'm still trying to figure out why `count` isn't defined though. Btw now I've checked that `CLISP` also warns when I use `compile-file` but w/o errors.

Answer (score 4):

First, note that `*count*` and `count` are two different things. Same goes for `*resLis*` and `resLis`.

Second, what's that `:` doing in the middle of `func1`?

Third, where's `anotherFunc`?

Fourth, don't use `defvar` in a function; those are for globals!

Once you work these out, you should find it easier to get going.

Comment: Thanks. Because I tried to simplify the question, I omitted what I thought is unnecessary (i.e. `:` and `anotherFunc`). And at `4th`, you might have meant `defvar`.

Comment: @IsaacS whoops, you're right! Could you perhaps clarify the intent of the code? It'd probably be helpful for us to help you. Is it trying to count the maximum depth of some nested lists?